# How to make a real time roulette in the website

Tags: javascript, html, css, websocket

I am learning some web developing and though I could make a web game just to practice some more.
So far I have made this fancy roulette with js, html and css:

[Codepen code](http://codepen.io/dealer/pen/YNvEGq)

The question now is how do I make it real time? Been looking around but couldn't find the answer. Do I have to use web sockets? `Node.js`? I'm lost. I want it to look the same for everyone not individually different once you open it. A simple point out to where I should look next would be perfect.

Also I am running it through the web server that I bought. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can keep this application running in your webserver and stream the data using [`socket.io`](https://socket.io/). Another option would be to use [`firebase`](https://firebase.google.com/).